# Is there a way to embed the Firefox JSONView (or similar) inside DRF's BrowseableAPI json nested-renderer?

Tags: json, firefox, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework's (DRF) BrowsableAPI renderer is very useful when the JSON to show is "small enough", but it struggles when the JSON is big. For example, in the image below the JSON is hard to read and the user has to scroll a lot(I even had to crop the image).

[image]

But when using Firefox's integrated JSONView, we can collapse each attribute and "interactively" read the JSON and I can even filter attributes. For example, in the image below I filter the attributes to show the ones that include the word "Population".

[image]

I inspected Firefox's integrated JSONView and apparently it uses a local HTML+JSON+CSS combination to render the JSON viewer, but I couldn't find an easy way to use it in DRF's BrowsableAPI.

Is there a way to embed it? Is there an alternative to make big JSONs more readable?

Comment: I am using the [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en) extension, seems best for you

Comment: I'm trying to find an alternative in the server side, not the client side.

Comment: Then, you might need to override the browsable API renders